# Step by step(screen shots) setup of nhibernate with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, installation

I am interested in looking for Step by step(screen shots) setup of nhibernate with asp.net mvc.... Any good links would be really useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out [Summer of Nhibernate](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/)
, it's pretty useful and I am sure they have great setup instructions as well. This is a screencast series so you not only get ScreenShots but videos :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to checkout the series on tekpub at http://tekpub.com/production/nhibernate